# C# Using CodeDom to add variables as part of a class

Tags: c#, codedom

I am attempting to create the following code through the use of CodeDom:

```
public partial class mainClass
{
    public byte[] bytes = null;
}
```

I have no problem creating the class, and I found ways to declare variables through the use of CodeDom using the `CodeVariableDeclarationStatement` method, but I am unsure of how to add a variable declaration as part of my class.

**Here is what I have tried thus far:**

```
CodeTypeDeclaration mainClass = new CodeTypeDeclaration("mainClass");
mainClass.IsPartial = true;
mainClass.IsClass = true;
mainClass.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public;
Namespaces.Types.Add(mainClass);

CodeVariableDeclarationStatement variableDeclaration = new(CodeVariableDeclarationStatement(typeof(byte[]), "bytes", new CodePrimitiveExpression("String.Empty");
```

I am open to any suggestions and ideas. Thank you for any help,
Evan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this

```
CodeMemberField field = new CodeMemberField(typeof(byte[]), "bytes");
field.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public;

mainClass.Members.Add(field);
```

Comment: Thank you. What if my declaration was to be part of a method, though. Would I use my original code?